# Add leading zeroes to a filename

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-processing

I am trying to modify a batch file created by somebody else, to add leading zeros depending on the number found on line 4 of the file. The actual filename is a concatenation of the name found on line 3, and the numbers on line 4. So if the first few lines are as follows:

```
3.1.19
-1
TEST
560
```

The file name would be v_TEST00560.TXT. As you can see, the total number of digits in the file name should be 5. If the number which appears on line 4 is 8 (see below), then:

```
3.1.19
-1
TEST
8
```

The file name will be v_TEST00008.txt.
The file I have is as follows:

```
@Echo Off 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM File: rename5.bat
REM The script will look for and parse one (or more) input files 
REM Input files can containrecords for one or more vessels.
REM This script assumes that each record starts with the "3.1.19" string.

REM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Configuration Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

SET INPUT_DIR=C:\Files\RenameFileName\Input
SET OUTPUT_DIR=C:\Files\RenameFileName\Output
SET ARCHIVE_DIR=C:\Files\RenameFileName\Archive
SET TEMP_DIR=C:\Files\RenameFileName\tmp
SET INPUT_FILENAME=INTERFACE.TXT
SET REC=3.1.19

REM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Checking Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= delims= " %%d IN (`date /t`) do SET RUNDATE=%%d
echo [%RUNDATE% %TIME%] Script starting...

IF NOT EXIST %INPUT_DIR% (
    SET MESSAGE=Input directory not found.
    goto END
)

IF NOT EXIST %OUTPUT_DIR% (
    SET MESSAGE=Output directory not found.
    goto END
)

IF NOT EXIST %ARCHIVE_DIR% (
    SET MESSAGE=Archive directory not found.
    goto END
)

IF NOT EXIST %TEMP_DIR% (
    echo Temporary directory does not exit. 
    echo Creating %TEMP_DIR%
    mkdir %TEMP_DIR%
)


REM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Processing %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

dir %INPUT_DIR%\%INPUT_FILENAME% 1>NUL 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    SET MESSAGE=Input files not present.
    goto END
) 

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= delims= " %%d IN (`date /t`) do SET RUNDATE=%%d
echo [%RUNDATE% %TIME%] Input files found. Start Processing...

FOR /F "usebackq" %%I IN (`dir /b %INPUT_DIR%\%INPUT_FILENAME%`) DO (
    SET INPUT_FILE=!INPUT_DIR!\%%I
    echo READING Input file: !INPUT_FILE!

    SET N=
    FOR /F "tokens=* eol= delims= "  %%A IN (!INPUT_FILE!) Do (
        set LINE=%%A
        set LINE2=!LINE:~0,6!
        if !LINE2! EQU !REC! (
            SET /A N+=1
            echo Creating temp file !TEMP_DIR!\!N!.tmp
        )
        echo !LINE! >> !TEMP_DIR!\!N!.tmp
    )

    FOR /F "usebackq" %%Y in (`dir /b !TEMP_DIR!\*.tmp`) DO (
        SET TEMPFILE=!TEMP_DIR!\%%Y
        SET N=
        FOR /F %%A IN (!TEMPFILE!) DO (
            SET /A N+=1
            IF !N! EQU 3 SET S=%%A
            IF !N! EQU 4 SET T=%%A
        )
        SET S=!S:~0,10!
        SET T=!T:~0,10!

        echo CREATING Output File: %OUTPUT_DIR%\V_!S!00!T!.TXT
        MOVE !TEMPFILE!  %OUTPUT_DIR%\V_!S!00!T!.TXT
    )
)

REM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Archiving Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

FOR /F "usebackq" %%t IN (`cscript "%~dp0timestamp.vbs" //Nologo`) do SET TIMESTAMP=%%t

FOR /F "usebackq" %%I IN (`dir /b %INPUT_DIR%\%INPUT_FILENAME%`) DO (
    echo ARCHIVING Input file %%I to %ARCHIVE_DIR%
    rem COPY !INPUT_DIR!\%%I !ARCHIVE_DIR!\%%I.!TIMESTAMP!
    MOVE !INPUT_DIR!\%%I !ARCHIVE_DIR!\%%I.!TIMESTAMP!
)

REM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= delims= " %%d IN (`date /t`) do SET RUNDATE=%%d
SET MESSAGE=[%RUNDATE% %TIME%] Processing Done.

:END
echo %MESSAGE%
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= delims= " %%d IN (`date /t`) do SET RUNDATE=%%d
echo [%RUNDATE% %TIME%] Script finished.
```

As you can see, its quite sophisticated, and I have no idea how to make these changes myself. The BAT runs perfectly, but the number of zeroes if fixed, and not generated depending on the number of digits already present. Any help appreciate

Answer (score 8):

I'm not about to read all of your code, but I use this for padding zeros.

The first line is whetever number you read from your file.
The second line pads more than enough zeros to the start of the variable.
The third line cuts off all but the last five characters from the variable.

```
Set Number=123

Set Number=00000%Number%
Set Number=%Number:~-5%
```

Comment: Great answer...I'm not sure how I forgot that.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for responding. I'm clueless when it comes to scripting, so this follow up question shouldn't suprise you. How do I get the script to select the number from line 4?

Comment: Hello again. I figured it out. Thanks again.